# SQL Server INSERT syntax

Tags: sql-server, insert

I am trying to insert the following text into a table cell, which is `varchar(8000)`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 * 
FROM  
    (SELECT TOP 10000 * 
     FROM 
        (SELECT DISTINCT 
             rklient, nimi + ISNULL('(' + UPPER(oleknimi) + ')' ,'') AS nimi,
             mkood, kommentaar, regkood,
             ISNULL(aadress + ' ','') AS aadress, 
             naitatel AS telefon, NULL AS lepingutelefon, 
             faks, email, www, NULL AS sisu, iprowid, 
             varvikood, klient, saitrank AS rank, emaid, 'F' AS typ, 
             infobaas, x, y, ISNULL(lahtiolekuaeg,'none') as lahtiolekuaeg, 
             lahtikomment, NULL AS koiksynid, paigutus, nimeviide, kupong  
         FROM 
             table_name WHERE reanr = '10') Tulemus) e 
WHERE 
    nimeviide IS NULL  
ORDER BY 
    rank DESC, iprowid
```

It gives me incorrect syntax. I suppose its because this: `'`

How do I workaround this?

Comment: How is this an "INSERT" syntax?

Answer (score 2):

You can quote the `'` character by simply doubling it `''`.

Example:

```
   SELECT 'This is q single quote ''';
```